# processing room database information

Tags: android, database, kotlin, mobile

ok so im quite new to using room, ive looked in a lot of places but find it hard to find my answer, alot of places ive looked around seem to have outdated information.

I have setup a room database, i have all the information for it set up as well as a viewmodel to send the infomration from. However i can not for the life of me figure out how to process the information in to android compose.

here is what i have done,any feedback would be good.

```
@Entity
data class Notes(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "header") val header: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "note") val note: String?
)
```

```
@Dao
interface NotesDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Notes>>

    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(notes: Notes)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(notes: Notes)
}
```

```
@Database(entities = [Notes::class], version = 1)
abstract class NotesAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun notesDao(): NotesDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: NotesAppDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): NotesAppDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    NotesAppDatabase::class.java,
                    "items_database"
                )
                    // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                    // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class NotesRepository (private val notesDao: NotesDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Notes>> = notesDao.getAll()

    suspend fun addNote(note: Notes){
        notesDao.insert(note)
    }
}
```

```
class NotesRepoViewModel (application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repo: NotesRepository
    private val allNotes: LiveData<List<Notes>>

    init {
        val dao = NotesAppDatabase.getDatabase(application).notesDao()
        repo = NotesRepository(dao)
        allNotes = repo.readAllData
    }

    fun notes(notes: Notes){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.addNote(notes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what you are looking for is how to observe data in UI right ?

Comment: @Mado yes, and also how to push the data to the notes function in "NotesRepoViewModel".  In other words im basically kind of lost after the point you see.

Comment: okay i understand, did you create Composable functions for your notes?, also texts for header and note?

Comment: here what i understand from you is that you didn't yet create the UI, if you already implemented the UI please provide your Composable functions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JayDee as the Community bot told you :)